# bidirectional communication between Raspberry Pi and Android Tablet over OTP USB cable?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, usb, android

I can root the Android tablet if needed.

Basically I'd like to be able to run Android apps on the tablet, but have a service running on the RP that can send and receive.

Sending RP->Tablet examples include: sending an interrupt to the Android tablet to change the current app, launching intents, etc.

Receiving Tablet->RP examples include: a microphone and/or camera input on the RP to be piped into the Android tablet and into apps that would normally use them.

Is this possible? Does the architecture of Android allow this?

If so, what hardware and software tools can I use to accomplish this?